# C# Structure - Forms, Panels and User Controls

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I use PHP all the time but am completeley new to C#. Obviously with webpages and apps everytime a user clicks a new page is loaded or javascript is used to inject content.

When designing my C# app with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express I am having trouble understanding how my app is supposed to structure. I have a form with buttons.... when a button is pressed it goes to that category and shows more buttons(Fairly Simple).

At first I was going to have a form with main buttons. When a button is pressed it closes and a new form opens. Apparantly this is not a good idea. I was than going to use panels on the one form which shows and than hidden as needed.

Now I am reading on the internet that I should be using User Controls????
If you think User Control than why bother having the panel? Why not just put the user controll on the form?

What is the correct way to reload content onto the form? The content will be dynamic from an SQL database.

Comment: This is a very broad question... there's no straight answer, do have one consideration... is there any reason you are using Winforms? If it's all new to you, you might just as well start with WPF, one of the many advantages to you will be that you can define the UI in a declarative way using XAML (you may be able to relate to your HTML skills that way). This will also allow you to use a navigation based application which is a lot like a web application with pages and forward/back buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. Usually winform applications have single main form, which contains a single panel - with tabs/user contols/buttons/etc, opening *modal* windows (on top of main form, which should be closed to come back to main form) or [MDI (multi-document)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface) interface, [(a nice example of implementation)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C), like Word/Photoshop/etc, when different documents open as child windows for main form and user can navigate between them back and forth. This can be used for multiple database records application. For example, main form with menu/toolbar (like outlook inbox/sent/etc), single window for searching documents, double-click - opens document details in a new window, etc.

You might use Panel or UserControl as a container, which fits your needs. Usually Panel is used just as container, while UserControl - as inherited control with some custom behavior/controls. You might add `Name [...textbox...]` UI into parent control. Or into inherited `UserInfoControl : UserControl` with Last Name, Birth Date, etc. And reuse it in multiple places.